# When hover on Image opacity doesn't apply

Tags: html, css

I have problem that when i hover on image its must use opacity + overlay text, and when text overlays the image opacity don't work correctly, what i did wrong in my code?

Here is CSS code

```
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid  white;
  overflow: hidden; }

  .grid:hover .text-overlay {
    display: block; }

  .grid img {
    width: 308px; }

  .grid .img-grid {
    display: block;
    position: relative; }
    .grid .img-grid:hover {
      opacity: .5; }

  .grid .text-overlay {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px; }
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xco6138d/)

Comment: @fcalderan Yes solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
.grid .img-grid:hover { opacity: .5; }
```

you should use

```
.grid:hover .img-grid { opacity: .5; }
```

because when the caption appears you lose the `hover` state on the `img` element

---

[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xco6138d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just Change

```
 .grid .img-grid:hover {
      opacity: .5; 
}
```

to

```
.grid:hover img {
      opacity: .5; 
}
```